# Dns prefetching with javascript

Tags: javascript, dns, prefetch

I'm changing the dns-prefetching href with javascript. I want to know if it is effective.
I'have 2 website that share the same javascript.

So i do something like this:

```
<link id="prefetching" href="//www.site1.com" rel="dns-prefetch" />




var currentDomain = document.domain;

if (currentDomain.contains("site1")) {
    $("prefetching").href = currentDomain.replace("site1", "site2");
    return;
}
if (currentDomain.contains("site2")) {
    $("prefetching").href = currentDomain.replace("site2", "site1");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't hurt to dns-prefetch both domains, simply by adding two `<link rel="dns-prefetch">` tags.

Waiting for the javascript to be run, before being able to interpret the (changed) `dns-prefetch` tags in the `<head>` of your document would undo the kind of improvement you're after.

Nonetheless, if you do want to find out if your method is working, in Chrome you can see the DNS-prefetching info by opening `chrome://dns/` in the address bar.